# How to add a new file with routes in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compiler-errors, routes, router

I have a main router.js file where I want to use the another file with routes - routeManagement.

router.js:

```
import routesManagement from './routesManagement'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  
  routesManagement,
]
export default router
```

routesManagement.js:

```
import Tools from '../../views/management/Tools.vue'

const routeManagement = [
    {
        path: '/tools',
        name: 'Tools',
        component: Tools
    },
]
export default routeManagement
```

When I do this, the app stops working and I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: [vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration.
```

How to fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructure the `routesManagement` array:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  
  ...routesManagement,
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :) But why `routesManagement`  must be destructure to works correct?

Comment: @Weronika The value of `routesManagement` its self is an array of objects, the top level `const routes` variable is expected to have an explicit shape to work with vue-router, which is a single parent array with child objects describing the shape of routes. By destructuring your `routesManagement` array, we adhere to this.